# Data packet, when sent over my SSL Socket becomes extremely large

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, sslsocketfactory

I have recently tried my hands over Socket Programming by creating an SSL Socket used to stream data live from a server with no success of course. When I analyze the data packets through Wireshark, I realize the size of request data has been magnified n number of times in the packet and hence the request reaches the server in fragments where as the actual JSON request is a handful of bytes and should reach the server in a single shot.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap a `BufferedOutputStream` around the `SSLSocket`'s output stream, and don't flush it until you really gotta, which is usually not until you're about to read the reply. Otherwise you can be sending one byte at a time to the `SSLSocket`, which becomes one SSL message per byte, which can expand the data by more than 40x.

However:

> the request reaches the server in fragments

That can happen any time. The server has to be able to cope with receiving data as badly fragmented as one byte at a time.

> where as the actual JSON request is a handful of bytes and should reach the server in a single shot.

There is no such guarantee in TCP.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Could you be a more illustrative with an example perhaps? I have seen a different program doing the same thing without using a BufferedOutputStream..ie. using a DataOutputStream with no expansion of data. What am i missing?

Comment: I don't know what you're missing, or what you don't understand about 'wrap a `BufferedOutputStream` around the `SSLSocket`'s output stream'. You seem to understand how to do it with a `DataOutputStream` after all.

Comment: I understand wrapping a BufferedOutputStream. :) . It's just the requirement over here is to have the request reach the server in a single packet and not  in fragments. And the JSON request here is 370 bytes yet I see 10 packets of 1370 bytes each reaching the server. Just elaborating my case. Any suggestions as I'm not sure why not using a BufferedOutputStream would cause a problem.

Comment: Thanks. it worked!!. However , I still have few doubts regarding its working. Another question perhaps ;)

Comment: The requirement isn't feasible, but this will certainly solve the data explosion problem. The server must still be coded defensively & not to assume everything arrives in a single read.